# Is there any formal definition of constants?

Tags: java, jls

Does the Java specification define the principle of constants, or is it left to a recommendation role?

If it is defined in the specifications, what is its definition?

Concretely, are any or all of the following examples considered as constants? If some or all indeed are, are they considered so following the specification, or any other official recommendation?

```
public static final int ONE = 1;
public static final double TWO = 2.0d;
public static final String THREE = "three";
public static final ImmutableList<Integer> ONE_TWO_THREE = ImmutableList.of(1, 2, 3);
public static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogManager().getLogger(ThisClass.class);
```

Comment: the Java spec say nothing about conventions. it only defines the set of compilation errors

Comment: there is no spec about this, there are recommendations; but there is no common standard.

Comment: while this is a document from Sun, this is not Java Language Specifications

Comment: I have given an identical answer.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire thx. I really don't know why the *fuss* about it honestly. If it helped you it might help others, so I posted it as an answer.

Comment: You didn't just "rephrase". You wrote it new from scratch, rendering the answers obsolete and irrelevant. You should have asked a new question.

Comment: and yes, **all** `static final` fields are constant in the sense that you can assign a value to them only once, during class initialization. This is enforced by the compiler. regardless of the variable name.

Comment: like I said, look at the answers, they look out of place and irrelevant.  Anyway, my last comment should give you an answer.

Comment: like I said, your "edit" is a complete re-write. that is the problem.

Comment: and you got an answer for your "improved" question. happy?

Comment: @SharonBenAsher: I disagree that this is a "complete rewrite". The substance of the question is unchanged: are `static final` variables always considered "constants" by Java?

Comment: deleted my answer as it was rendered useless after the question was edited

Comment: the only answer at the moment is WRONG, but it is only so because of the "improvement" edit

Comment: @NicolBolas, it is a "complete rewrite" because the original question mentioned a supposed difference between "value" based variables and "business" variables (whatever that means) and that what everyone answered about

Comment: you didn't remove a  footnote, you removed the main point of the question.

Comment: @SharonBenAsher: There wasn't much room for ambiguity about what the question was asking. It said very clearly, "are indiscriminately all `static final` fields constants? Or does the spec allow me to decide which fields are constants?" The matter of "value" or "business" was merely an example.

Comment: i voted to close because the original question was about naming convention - an opinion based topic

Comment: @SharonBenAsher No, the original question *wasn't* about naming conventions.  The original question was asking exactly what the question is *now* asking.  It was *never* asking about naming conventions.

Comment: perhaps it should have been closed on "unclear what youre asking for".  happy?

Comment: @SharonBenAsher Indeed, there were quite a number of people that misunderstood the question.  The question wasn't clearly written in order to effectively convey what it was asking.  It has since been clarified to address that problem.

Comment: fine. I stand corrected. the accurate reason for closure should have been "unclear what youre asking for".  I'm happy.

Comment: However, I stand "firm in my boots" that the rewrite was indeed a new question, not a clarification.  This is because answers were already posted about the unclear version

Comment: @SharonBenAsher Go to [meta to discuss it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/346440/my-question-is-being-close-voted-as-opinion-based-i-edit-it-before-the-5th-vote).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are two uses of *constant* in the Java language. There are *constant expressions* and those are defined in the specification. See [Chapter 15.28 Constant Expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28)

> A constant expression is an expression denoting a value of primitive
>   type or a String that does not complete abruptly and is composed using
>   only the following:
>
> - Literals of primitive type and literals of type `String` (§3.10.1, §3.10.2, §3.10.3, §3.10.4, §3.10.5)
> - Casts to primitive types and casts to type String (§15.16)
> - The unary operators `+`, `-`, `~`, and `!` (but not `++` or `--`) (§15.15.3, §15.15.4, §15.15.5, §15.15.6)
> - The multiplicative operators `*`, `/`, and `%` (§15.17)
> - The additive operators `+` and `-` (§15.18)
> - The shift operators `<<`, `>>`, and `>>>` (§15.19)
> - The relational operators `<`, `<=`, `>`, and `>=` (but not `instanceof`) (§15.20)
> - The equality operators `==` and `!=` (§15.21)
> - The bitwise and logical operators `&`, `^`, and `|` (§15.22)
> - The conditional-and operator `&&` and the conditional-or operator `||` (§15.23, §15.24)
> - The ternary conditional operator `? :` (§15.25)
> - Parenthesized expressions (§15.8.5) whose contained expression is a constant expression.
> - Simple names (§6.5.6.1) that refer to constant variables (§4.12.4).
> - Qualified names (§6.5.6.2) of the form `TypeName . Identifier` that refer to constant variables (§4.12.4).

If you follow the link for [*constant variables*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4), you'll find

> A blank `final` is a `final` variable whose declaration lacks an
>   initializer.
>
> A constant variable is a `final` variable of primitive type or type
>   `String` that is initialized with a constant expression (§15.28).
>   Whether a variable is a constant variable or not may have implications
>   with respect to class initialization (§12.4.1), binary compatibility
>   (§13.1, §13.4.9), and definite assignment (§16 (Definite Assignment)).

So `static` is not required. The Java language only cares that the variable is `final` and initialized at its declaration with a constant expression.

There are also [*enum constants*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9.1) which are the enum instances.

---

Other uses are developer uses to refer to something that doesn't change (whether it's a non-constant `final` variable or something else). Careful how you use those in conjunction with the *constants* above.

---

That being said, your examples contain variables, which are considered constants according to the above mentioned specification as well as those, which are not. The first three variables are `final` and of primitive type or of type `String` and are, thus, *constant variables*:

```
public static final int ONE = 1;
public static final double TWO = 2.0d;
public static final String THREE = "three";
```

Although being declared `final`, the last two variables are **not** to be considered constant variables, because they are neither of primitve type nor of type `String`:

```
public static final ImmutableList<Integer> ONE_TWO_THREE = ImmutableList.of(1, 2, 3);
public static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogManager().getLogger(ThisClass.class);
```

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire Hence, looking at the original examples from [rev. 2](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/43207857/2) of your post, both `public static final ImmutableList<Integer> ONE_TWO_THREE` as well as `private static final Logger logger` are **not** to be considered *constant variables* because they are neither variables of primitive type nor of type `String`.

Comment: @altocumulus this is indeed one of the important part I wanted to highlight when I read this. It's not explicitly written, but thank you for doing doing this.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire As this is a community wiki post you are free to edit it as you see fit. Personally, I'd prefer to have at least the examples of rev. 2 back in your question and the information from my comment incorporated in the answer.