# Compile-time constants when using object reference in Java

Tags: java, compilation, constants, runtime, final

I'm learning about compile-time constants and I want to ask you if that `instance.maximumLoginAttempts` expression is a compile-time constant. I don't think it is because in my opinion instance reference is obtained at runtime, so the compiler doesn't know that the value of `instance.maximumLoginAttempts` is 5. Is that correct? Thank you!

```
    public class CompileTimeVariables {
            public final int maximumLoginAttempts = 5;
        
            public static void main(String[] args) {
        
                CompileTimeVariables instance = new CompileTimeVariables();
                System.out.println(instance.maximumLoginAttempts);
            }
   }
```

Comment: Right, "constants" have to also be `static` or there's not a compile time value.  What you have there is just an ordinary runtime value.

Comment: Related: [*Is there any formal definition of constants?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43207857/642706)

Comment: @markspace Can I say maximumLoginAttempts and also instance.maximumLoginAttempts are runtime constants?

Comment: I would say `maximumLoginAttempts` is `final`.  Try to not introduce unclear terminology.  I would not say `instance` is a constant because it isn't even final.